# Holder's inequality on weighted $L^p$ space

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, holder-inequality

Let $v(x,z)$ be a function, where $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$ is a $d$-dimensional real vector and $z\in(0,\infty)$. Let $D\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be a domain and $|\alpha|<1$. Consider the space $L^2(z^{\alpha},D)$ with its norm defined by
$$
\|v\|^2_{L^2(z^{\alpha},D)}=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{D}z^{\alpha}|v|^2dxdz.
$$

I am trying to apply Holder's inequality, for example $\|fg\|_{L^2(D)}\leq \|f\|_{L^{\infty}(D)}\|g\|_{L^2(D)}$. In this weighted space above, I am wondering how should we do it. Does the following make sense?
$$
\|vw\|_{L^2(z^{\alpha},D)}\leq \max_{z>0}\|w\|_{L^{\infty}(D)}\|v\|_{L^2(z^{\alpha},D)} 
$$

Comment: Define the measure $\mu(dx,dy)=\mathbb{1}_D(x) v(x,y)\,dxdy$ on Borel subsets of $\mathbb{r}^d\times \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

You can do better in fact and easily have $$\|vw\|_{L^2(z^\alpha,D)}^2=\int_0^\infty\int_Dz^\alpha |v|^2(x)|w|^2(x)dxdz\leq\int_0^\infty\int_Dz^\alpha |v|^2(x)\|w\|_{L^\infty(D)}^2 dz=\|w\|_{L^\infty(D)}\int_0^\infty\int_Dz^\alpha |v|^2(x)dxdz=\|w\|_{L^\infty(D)}^2\|v\|_{L^2(z^\alpha,D)}^2 $$ Taking the square root gives the result without the maximum over $z$.

Comment: $0^\infty$? Typo?